# Fetch info to CKEditor text box?

Tags: ckeditor, fetch

Okay, i explain by images!
Adding Film
http://i.gyazo.com/97d676b7eeb67235019d0f0b6c0ad78b.png "Adding film!"
Its fine!

```
<p><strong>Synopsis
<br />
<span style="color:#FF0000;">No special characters like <strong>&#39;</strong> or <strong>&quot;</strong> in synopsis!</span>
<form>
<textarea name="synopsis" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
</form>
```

Edit film, so in this text box that film info what i added "Synopsis" won't show in this text box!
http://i.gyazo.com/a41d22fdb5e2153f4877e183c9f74627.png "Edit film!" Not fine!

```
<p><strong>Synopsis
<br />
<span style="color:#FF0000;">No special characters like <strong>&#39;</strong> or <strong>&quot;</strong> in synopsis!</span>
<form>
<textarea name="synopsis" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" value="<?php echo ''.$fetch['synopsis'].'';?>">
</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please improve your question - explain what is the expected result and what have you tried so far.

Comment: What i want is, When i adding film to my site, and if i need edit to it, that film Synopsis wont show in CKEditor text box when i edit that! So when i added film Synopsis it wont show in edit page!

Comment: The problem with your description is that "edit" and "add" as well as "won't show" are extremely imprecise terms. I've got still no idea what you do.

Comment: Added better explaining and code in first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You try to put the content inside the textarea tag?

Like this :

```
    <p>
        <strong>Synopsis
        <br />
        <span style="color:#FF0000;">No special characters like <strong>&#39;</strong> or <strong>&quot;</strong> in synopsis!</span>
    </p>
    <form>
        <textarea name="synopsis" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            <?php echo ''.$fetch['synopsis'].'';?>
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </form>
```

And you should close the paragraph tag like I did in the code I show. That prevent some side effects.